# How is function parameter defined?

Tags: haskell, currying

For this function :

```
plus1 = (+) 1
```

I can use :

```
Prelude> plus1 3
4
```

The type of plus1 is

```
plus1 :: Integer -> Integer
```

How is function parameter Integer being allowed here ? In my function definition where is the Integer function parameter defined ?

I'm not sure what I expect to happen but coming from Java all parameters need to be defined as part of the method but there seems to be something going on behind the scenes here ?

Comment: Your use of the phrase "function parameter" is a bit confusing to me at least. Can you state more explicitly what you thought would happen versus what is happening?

Comment: This example is actually used in explaining curried functions, see here: http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html.

Comment: There's actually less "behind the scenes" here than in Java. In Haskell, functions are just values, and it's perfectly reasonable to define a function as the result of an expression. The expression just happens to have function type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(If we ignore the `Num` typeclass for a moment and pretend that + works on `Integer`s only for simplicity's sake,) `(+)` is a function of type `Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)` (the parentheses aren't necessary because `->` is right-associative, but I've added them for clarity). That means it takes an argument of type `Integer` and produces a function of type `Integer -> Integer` as its result.

So when you apply `(+)` to the Integer `1`, you do indeed get a function of that type as the result. Since `add1` holds that result, it is thus a function of type `Integer -> Integer` and that's why you can apply it as `plus1 3`.

Comment: +1, It's hard to understand currying but if you know Java/Javascript, you need to think of `add` as `function add(o1) { return function(o2) { return o1 + o2; } }`, and calling it as `add(1)(2)`.  Then it should be clear what `add(1)` actually is.